# How to change the time for OS selection menu in GRUB?

Tags: 12.04, grub2, dual-boot

I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 in my system and i saw that the default time for os selection menu is only 10 sec, as i am new to Linux can anyone tell me how to increase this time?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>
- Type command, `gksu gedit /etc/default/grub`
- change the `GRUB_TIMEOUT` value to 15 or 20 as required. (value in second)
  or Setting timeout to -1 will make GRUB wait indefinitely until you manually select an entry and hit enter,
  It should look like

  `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10`
- save it. Close gedit. Now open a terminal and run

  `sudo update-grub`

Comment: I required root privileges to edit the grub file else it was giving access denied error as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/364008/605028)

Answer (score 14):

You need to edit `/etc/default/grub` file by opening a terminal and running this command: `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

You need to set the value of `GRUB_TIMEOUT` to how long (in seconds) you want the grub menu to appear. `GRUB_TIMEOUT` is actually the number of seconds before the default entry is automatically booted. If you want to see the menu for 10 seconds which is the default, then do:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

Also, make sure that you add # before the GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0 line:

```
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

Then do a `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Answer (score 6):

I used to use startup manager, as pointed out by Chad--24216, but alas, it's no longer being maintained, nor is it in the repositories.

It has been superseded by "grub-customizer", which while up to date, is also not in the standard repositories. To to add and install it simply do the following at the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
```

Press enter to confirm adding the PPA

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Press Y to confirm

You can now launch grub-customizer in the usual ways.  If you ignore the complete list you'll see when it first launches, and just press "Preferences" button on the toolbar you'll get a nice summary dialog where you can change the timeout value and default menu item, as shown below:

[image: Grub Customizer preferences screen]

Sources:

[Startup Manager is dead](https://launchpad.net/startup-manager/+announcement/8300)

[Grub Customizer PPA](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/grub-customizer?field.series_filter=precise)

Comment: Grub Customizer is good but sometimes creates issues when upgrading the distro, So avoid it until one needs it and remember to remove this before distro upgrade

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to do it

1. [Start-up Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/startupmanager/) (Development discontinues)
2. Grub customiser  (Not in the official repositories as yet)

---

**Using Start-up manager** (available upto 12.04)

Install it by typing:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install startupmanager
```

1. Open up `start-up manager`
2. Change the timeout setting to 10 secs

   [image]

---

**Using Grub Customiser**

1. To to add and install it simply do the following at the terminal (You need to add a PPA):

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer`

   Press enter, then type

   `sudo apt-get update`
   `sudo apt-get install grub-customizer`

   And press **Y** to confirm

   [image: Grub Customizer preferences screen]
2. Click on the `General` tab and change the time out to 10 secs

---

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is startup manager installed by default?. Also I heard, that project is dead now.

Comment: @AnwarShah the op hasnt specified his OS version... the older OS has startup manager, doesnt it?

Comment: In that case, you can clarify the OP. Also, I don't think startup manager was included in the previous releases

Comment: @AnwarShah i'll include the option for newer versions of ubuntu also.

Comment: @AnwarShah edited my answer.. see if it fits what you wanted.

Comment: I am not the OP. But yes, your answer now look good. Thanks

Comment: Sorry guys, I forgot to include that, but I am running 12.04 .    Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thanks For This Answer! I'm using 12.04 And I customized time of GRUB by using "GRUB Customizer"! The Second Way U noted above! Thank U Very Much!

Answer (score 0):

Web-E's answer is really the best way to do it. However, if you want a GUI way of modifying GRUB that doesn't involve editing a file, you can download an install "startupmanager" from USC or Synaptic. Or with Universe repo enabled, you can open Terminal and install by typing:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install startupmanager
```

Comment: startup manager package is not available in 12.04 .

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the timeout for grub.
Have a look at this guide for really simple instructions on changing grub's timeout / os selection time :

[how to change the time for os selection menu in grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135113/how-to-change-the-time-for-os-selection-menu-in-grub)

Comment: The link really points to this same question. Funny!