# How do I make GRUB appear at startup without holding shift?

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, startup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the time for OS selection menu in GRUB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135113/how-to-change-the-time-for-os-selection-menu-in-grub)

I have a dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu. Whenever I start my computer it will go straight into linux unless I hold shift to go into GRUB.   I am constantly having to change between operating systems and my keyboad configuration doesn't allow for my to press shift at startup.  Is there a way I can make it go to GRUB even if the shift key isn't pressed?
Thank you!