# When I try to save any file, it gives me "Permission Denied"

Tags: grub2, permissions, password, gksudo

It doesn't matter where, it just won't save any files. I have tried running `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`, because I am trying to change the `quiet splash` to `elevator=deadline` but when I try to save it, "Permission Denied"

When I type `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`, it prompts me for a password, then nothing opens. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Well, normally you don't have permissions to modify `/etc/default/grub`, but you can do it with root privileges:

```bsh
sudo -i                   #to get root permissions
gedit /etc/default/grub   #to edit /etc/default/grub
```

If your `gedit` still doesn't open, try to reinstall it (using `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gedit` command) or use `nano` instead (`nano /etc/default/grub`).

Comment: The `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub` should imply he is getting the permission to edit the file.

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen As you can see, I suggested him to reinstall `gedit`.

Comment: Okay, turns out, Gedit wasn't installed. So I did what you said Radu, as well as installing Gedit and it worked. Thanks for all you help guys and gals :)