# How to modify waiting time of the dual boot menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot

How can I change the waiting time of the dual boot menu (starting moment) into my Ubuntu Studio 15.10 installation? Can I?

Answer (score 5):

Open a terminal window, then back up the existing grub config file:

`sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub-backup`

Now (using `sudo` or `gksudo` depending on your editor of choice) edit `/etc/default/grub` and change the number in this line of the file

`GRUB_TIMEOUT=10`

to your desired waiting time in seconds.

Exit, saving the file, and then run

`sudo update-grub`

On your next  boot you should have the wait time you specified.

Comment: Creating a backup of grub file is a very good idea to recover from a  messed up situation. Btw, I required root privileges to edit the grub file else it was giving access denied error as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/364008/605028)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I have edited the answer to fix that.