# Can not turn off GRUB Menu

Tags: 14.04, grub2

There seems to be a lot of info on the web on how to turn off grub menu on a dual boot system (Ubuntu 14.04/Windows7) and a whole lot of answers which all seem to end in "It didn't work"!

Is there a way to do it???

I have done all the things suggested and "It didn't work"!! APPARENTLY there is NO way to correct this problem currently.

Comment: what do you mean by turn off? you mean hide it?

Comment: Do you think about restoring (or installing) new Windows bootloader? You can do it with any Windows installer cd, but I'm not sure that it will read Linux. Other way is to install bootloader through windows or linux, *but you do it for your own risk*.

Comment: You can install Grub Customizer and set timer 0 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/135113/how-to-change-the-time-for-os-selection-menu-in-grub

Answer (score 1):

To hide the grub menu follow the steps:

1. In the terminal, type:

`sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

2. Find the line that says:

`GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false`

and change it to `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true`

3. Find the line that says:

`GRUB_TIMEOUT=<some number here, eg: 10>`

and change it to:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=1
```

This will show the menu, but for just a second and after that it will boot the default entry. If it is set to `0`, still you will see it for 10 seconds as a security measure. So put `1` there.

4. Save and close the file.
5. Run `sudo update-grub`

Try and post back if there are any errors.

Comment: Tried it, and it did'nt work.   got this error :~$ sudo update-grub
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 9: /etc/default/grub: 4: not found

Comment: Edit your question to contain the output of `cat /etc/default/grub`

Comment: GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

Comment: put the complete output  in your question by [editing](http://askubuntu.com/posts/620174/edit) it.