# Force GRUB menu to choose my OS

Tags: boot, grub2, lubuntu

I've installed Lubuntu on a pc. When the pc turns off incorrectly, sometimes, at the next boot, the grub menu appears and it wait for my choise.
I would like to run my os, every times and in any case, without to show GRUB menu.
How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135113/how-to-change-the-time-for-os-selection-menu-in-grub) is your answer. You can reduce the Timeout of GRUB and then on expiration it will automatically run currently selected OS, which in your case will be "your OS"

Comment: No, It doesn't work. Sorry if I reply now. After a forced power off, on the boot, the GRUB appears and it waits my choose.