# Increase the boot selection time for windows 11 and ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I have windows 11 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS as dual boot. I would like to to increase the boot selection time

Answer (score 0):

Answer copied from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/163877/1382871), credit to user [peachy](https://askubuntu.com/users/74307/peachy)

You need to edit `/etc/default/grub` file by opening a terminal and running this command: `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

You need to set the value of `GRUB_TIMEOUT` to how long (in seconds) you want the grub menu to appear. `GRUB_TIMEOUT` is actually the number of seconds before the default entry is automatically booted. If you want to see the menu for 10 seconds which is the default, then do:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

Also, make sure that you add # before the GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0 line:

```
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

Then do a `sudo update-grub` and reboot.